# Xpath get text content from multiple and complicated tags

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

I have this HTML template:

```
<center>
    <img src="image1">
    <br><br>
    <img src="image2">
    <br><br>
    <strong><em>TITLE1 :</em></strong> DESC1<br>
    <strong><em>TITLE2 :</em></strong> DESC2<br>
    <strong><em>TITLE3 :</em></strong> DESC3<br>
    <strong><em>TITLE4 :</em></strong> DESC4<br>
    <strong><em>TITLE5 :</em></strong> DESC5<br><br><br>
    <img src="image3">
    <br><br><br>DESC_GEN
</center>
```

I want to use xpath to get this expected result:

```
TITLE 1 = DESC 1
TITLE 2 = DESC 2
TITLE 3 = DESC 3
TITLE 4 = DESC 4
TITLE 5 = DESC 5
general = DESC_GEN
```

In an array so i can use the values elsewhere in my code.

This is what I have tried:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query("//em");
foreach($elements as $e) {
    echo $e->nodeValue . '<br/>';
}
```

But unfortunatelly this returns only TITLE 1, TITLE 2, TITLE 3 etc.

I want get their respective values (In this case DESC 1, DESC 2 etc ...).

What is the approach I can take to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, the HTML template you are using is not a well formed xml document. It may or may not cause problems depending on your parser.

The easiest way to get what you want is probably to first get the list of titles with

```
//em/text()
```

Then get the list of descriptions with

```
//em/following::text()[1]
```

Then the general description with

```
//center/text()[last()]
```

Finally just do some string manipulation to get it to the form that you want.

Note that the actual xpath expressions may vary depending on the specific HTML document. However the above should work for the template that you provided.

Answer (score 0):

walk to the parent `em` which is `strong` or `..` in xpah then select `text()`

```
$elements = $xpath->query("//em");
foreach($elements as $e) {
    $desc = $xpath->query("../following-sibling::text()", $e);
    echo $e->nodeValue . $desc[0]->nodeValue ."<br/>";
}
```